# Redux-form: How to get items count in FieldArray form?

Tags: redux-form

I have a form like that:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <FieldArray name="items"/>

  {???fields.length??? && <div className="controls">

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

  </div>}

</form>
```

I want to show submit button only if I have at least one line. How I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [form value selectors](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/FormValueSelector.md/), but it would be better to define good validation rules instead. You can write validation functions and then you will have valid props send to your form.

Than you can write something like

```
{this.props.valid && <div className="controls">

<button type="submit">Submit</button>

</div>}
```

Comment: I don't want use selectors. But validation... Hm. It's interesting. Will think about it, thanks

Comment: As of redux-form 6, I don't think there is other option than using selectors (which is basically just looking into redux store) to get values. You may also check dirty value because initially form can look like valid one.

Comment: If I will add line and will remove then, form props are: `invalid=false, pristine=false, dirty=true`

Comment: what are your validation rules?

Comment: I not check `items` length in validation yet. I just wanted to show `dirty` value